# Main C Program does not find header and methods

Tags: compilation, runtime, program-entry-point

Wasn't really sure how to explain this any better in the title. Basically I am learning how to separate my code in C. I have a main, the equivalent of an ArrayList class from java (but converted to c and is very basic) and a header file which declares my struct and all the functions in use. I am using all sample code out of the text and I am using the latest version of dev c++ for windows 8.

Every time I try to compile main I get:
In function main undefined reference to "newList"
[Error] Id returned 1 exit status

Here is my code:

```
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ArrayList.h"

int main(int numParms, char *parms[]){
     list myList;
     myList = newList(myList);

     printf("End");
     return 0;  
}

ArrayList.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ArrayList.h"

list newList(list myList){
 myList.size = 0;
 return myList;
}

list add(list myList, int value){
  myList.values[myList.size] = value;
  myList.size++;
  return myList;
  }

int get(list myList, int position){
  int entry;
  entry = myList.values[position];
  return entry;
}

int size(list myList){
 return myList.size;
}

list delete(list myList, int position){
     int count;
   for(count =0; count<(myList.size-1); count++){
        myList.values[count] = myList.values[count+1];
   }
   myList.size --;
   return myList;
}

void print(list myList){
int count;
printf("Current list contents:\n");
if (myList.size > 0){
    for (count=0; count<myList.size; count++){
        printf("Element %d is %d\n", count, get(myList, count));
        }
    printf("\n");
}
else{
    printf("The list is empty\n\n");
}
 }

ArrayList.h
#define MAX_SIZE 100
typedef struct{ 
int size;
int values[MAX_SIZE];       
 }list;

 list newList(list);
 list add(list, int);
 int get(list, int);
 int size(list);
 list delete(list, int);
 void print(list);
```

Comment: How do you compile your main.c ?

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a linker problem. The compilation is OK, but when the linker tries to assemble the pieces it can't find newList anywhere. My guess would be that you did not compile the file ArrayList.c and link the result to your project.